# Prove continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. Assume that whenever $x_n$ approaches $x$, it follows that $f_n(x_n)$ approaches $f(x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. How to show that $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example:$$f_n(x_n)=1+\frac{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}{nx_n},$$ and let $$x_n=1+\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$$

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor 2 \sin\left(\frac{x\cdot\pi}{2}\right)-0.1\right\rfloor$$

We have $x_n \to 1$ as $n \to\infty$, and $f_n(x_n)\to f(1)=1$, but $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: You know there's a very simple counterexample with all $x_n$ equal to a fixed value $x$, and $f_n$ a fixed non-continuous function equal to $f$.